# SQL Constraint : only one record per day for a particular key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

There is a way to create a constraint or something where I can have only one record for a Day for a FK column? I.E.

```
PK(IDENTITY(1,1))  FK_FIELD DATETIME
------------------------------
1                  1        2012-02-22 4:50 p.m.
2                  2        2012-02-23 12:00 p.m.
3                  2        2012-02-23 9:00 p.m.  -- This one should not be allowed because the FK_Field 2 would have 2 record in one day.
4                  1        2012-02-23 08:00 a.m
```

Hopefully someone understand what im trying to archieve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a field that is the date without time and add that to the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using:

- 1 or many persisted computed column(s)
- Unique constraint on the persisted computed column(s)

Some examples of a variety of persisted columns (Much thanks to Aaron Bertrand):

- Y AS YEAR(SOMEDATE) PERSISTED
- M AS MONTH(SOMEDATE) PERSISTED
- D AS MONTH(SOMEDATE) PERSISTED
- YMD AS YEAR(SOMEDATE) * 10000 + MONTH(SOMEDATE) * 100 + DAY(SOMEDATE) PERSISTED
- SOMEDATEDIFF AS DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, SOMEDATE) PERSISTED
- SOMEDATESMALL AS DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, SOMEDATE)) PERSISTED
- SOMEDATESMALL AS CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, SOMEDATE, 105)), 105) PERSISTED
- SOMEDATESMALL AS CONVERT(DATE, SOMEDATE) PERSISTED  -- Requires SQL Server 2008

N.B. These examples were chosen carefully to ensure function determinism.

Here's a sample SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA
(
     ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
     FK_FIELD INT NOT NULL,
     SOMEDATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
     SOMEDATESMALL AS DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, SOMEDATE)) PERSISTED,
     CONSTRAINT PK_DATA PRIMARY KEY (ID),
     CONSTRAINT UQ_DATA_SOMEDATESMALL UNIQUE (FK_FIELD, SOMEDATESMALL)
);
```

If you attempted the INSERTs, this is what you get:

```
INSERT INTO DATA (FK_FIELD, SOMEDATE) VALUES (1, '2012-02-22 4:50PM'); -- SUCCESS
INSERT INTO DATA (FK_FIELD, SOMEDATE) VALUES (2, '2012-02-23 12:00PM'); -- SUCCESS
INSERT INTO DATA (FK_FIELD, SOMEDATE) VALUES (2, '2012-02-23 9:00PM'); -- CAUGHT
INSERT INTO DATA (FK_FIELD, SOMEDATE) VALUES (1, '2012-02-23 8:00AM'); -- SUCCESS
```

The message shown in SQL Server Management Studio is:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_DATA_SOMEDATESMALL'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DATA'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Good idea, but three int columns is much more expensive than a smalldatetime column. `YMD as CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', SOMEDATE))` I'd post this as an answer but I think yours is too similar.

Comment: +1 Aaron it is a good suggestion to collapse to a single field. Because I wanted to use a Unique Constraint (not a Unique Index), the column had to be deterministic so I had to avoid using the CONVERT function.

Comment: yes good point, but you can still use `SMALLDATETIME` if you change `19000101` to `0` - the non-determinism is not caused by `CONVERT` itself, but rather by the interpretation of a string literal (which in the case of `YYYYMMDD` can't be misinterpreted, but I suppose SQL Server doesn't really look at the string).

Comment: The reason I push for `SMALLDATETIME`, by the way, is that the index could be used for other things such as date range queries - if you're going to pay 4 bytes for an index, it may as well serve other purposes too. :-)

Comment: One more thing, if the OP is on SQL Server 2008 (oh how I wish everyone specified - the generic `sql-server` tag should be rejected) you can just say `AS CONVERT(DATE, SOMEDATE)` which eliminates the need to trim time.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a check constraint that uses a user defined function that checks the whole table for an existence of a todays entry.

```
CREATE TABLE #demo (
    some_date_field DATETIME NULL 
        CHECK (dbo.check_only_one(GETDATE())
)
```

Comment: sound like a good idea, I like the @Bycycle, and "Spark answers, but what I don't like is that the table is going to be significant large, that computed column will use a lot of space that will be used just as a constraint, thats why i dont like them at all. What should be the return type of the User defined function?

Comment: The return could be as simple as a boolean indicating if it is valid to insert it or not

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach

```
create table t1 (pk int identity(1,1),fk_field int,theDate DateTime,
                 theDay as convert(varchar(12),theDate,102))
create unique index noDupes on t1 (fk_field,theDay)
```

You can also use a constraint, as Aaron suggested

```
create table t1 (pk int identity(1,1),fk_field int,theDate DateTime,
                     theDay as convert(varchar(12),theDate,102)
    CONSTRAINT [noDupes] UNIQUE  ( [fk_field], [theDay])        )
```

- Add a computed column that holds just the date portion of the date.
- Then create a unique index on the key and that computed field

  ```
  insert into  t1 values (1,getDate())        
  insert into  t1 values (2,getDate())          
  insert into  t1 values (2,getDate())    -- ERROR    
  insert into  t1 values (3,getDate())
  ```

Comment: If it's a constraint (which it is), I strongly recommend scripting it as a constraint, not an index. While under the covers the implementation is the same, the logical intention is quite different.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, good point, I've updated the answer to show the constraint as well

Answer (score 0):

I would try to separate the date from the time either in 2 different fields of the database or by composition. Then I would add a unique constraint on the date. The following would prevent any entry to be made for a same date as long as only the date is in the collumn you add the constraint to.

```
ALTER TABLE XYZ
    ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE( the date field name)
```

There is also a quite interesting thread you should check with a similar problem that was solved here [How to create a unique constraint just on the date part of a datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620561/how-to-create-a-unique-constraint-just-on-the-date-part-of-a-datetime)

Hope this helps

Comment: I think it could be a good approach, but to store the time in a different column I should have a time colum, and it is only supported since sql server 2008, sorry i didn't specified that, if I want to I  could store them as number, i'm going to think about it, but I think i would need to change a lot of things to archieve this. Thanks eitherway for your time!