# Create a query that do not allow me to enter the same number in the same year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I creating a software that allows me save documents. The problem is that
i need to create a query that does not allow me to save the same number
in the same year. (im new to sql).

Please any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The same number of what?

Comment: can you provide some sample data of what you would like to see and what is invalid as it's hard to guess this kind of stuff

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620561/how-to-create-a-unique-constraint-just-on-the-date-part-of-a-datetime

Comment: how about a check constraint.

Comment: Sorry for been so general, the number is the the Registry number of the document, it can only be used one per year. The program that im creating is in C#, tell me if it is easier to do it on the database or through the program. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "number" refers to document number and "year" refers to a field in the database, you would do this by creating a unique index:

```
create index docs_number_year on docs(number, [year]);
```

This will prevent any duplicates.

If, instead, you have a date in the column, you can create "year" as a computed column and then add the index:

```
alter table docs add [year] as year(DocumentDate);

create index docs_number_year on docs(number, [year]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that with a query, but rather with a Key. If you have column "Year" and column "number", you may define a primary key over both columns Year and Number (google for "multi-column key"), thus restricting the INSERT statement to only succeed if the combination of Year and Number is not yet in the database.

If you don't have these two columns, you're unlucky because my crystal ball is in the repair shop...

Comment: I think that's more correctly called a "unique constraint." It doesn't necessarily follow from the OP's question that these fields should comprise the primary key.

Comment: Yes im my table i have a column call Date and another call Registry_number.

Comment: But i only need the year of Date, the Date column is a datetime type in the database.